# how to include r prefix to a string in an loop?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings (these strings are basically addresses). Without using r prefix, there are some changes with the split option. With the addition of r prefix to a single string, the split option works fine. How to add r prefix to a list of strings to split with backslash accordingly?

```
all_address=['C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\5_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim','C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\10_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim','C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\15_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim']

all_address[0].split('\\') # ---- Not splitting correct
```

individual check as below is fine.

```
file_name=r'C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\5_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim'
file_name.split('\\')
['C:', 'Users', 'Desktop', 'post_calc_actions', '5_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim']
```

I expect the split as ['C:', 'Users', 'Desktop', 'post_calc_actions', '5_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim'] from loop

Comment: Your `all_address` Will raise errors because you didn't use the `r` flag.

Comment: `all_address=[r'C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\5_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim',r'C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\10_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim',r'C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\15_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim']`

Comment: ya. I understood that Paritosh. but how to prefix r for all_address in a loop to use split option accordingly.

Comment: @LinPy: Lets take all_address is given as above. How to add r iteratively to use split option?

Comment: if you have the `all_address` as i wrote it , then just use `all_address[0].split('\\')`

Comment: basically I'm expecting my output as '5_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim', '10_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim', '15_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim' from all_address=['C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\5_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim','C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\10_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim','C:\Users\Desktop\post_calc_actions\15_Hm_2.79_T_5_0.sim']

Comment: @LinPy: unfortunately, i dont have all_address that way. what i'm looking is.. how to add r prefix for a list of address, So that I can split it easily for picking the desired later.

Comment: @KGV How are getting the address ? The current address list strings are using the `\ ` escape character, you need to use r prefix.

Comment: you can not since the list is broken

Comment: Is it not possible to add r prefix to each of the list and then use split option? Actually I'm obtaining this from some code output which throws different for each work. From which i got to split to take the file_name accordingly.

Comment: You output script should produced the correct format

Comment: @KGV In that case, i think you misunderstand how the output is actually stored. The `r` flag isn't just some magic you can add later, it's an instruction to not parse things like `\n` as newlines and so on. Hence, the example given here is not really how your data is actually "Stored" per se. If the data is coming from somewhere, it would be correctly stored in memory.

Comment: Maybe you should read the print file from python code, rather than type what you see. because the `r` flag may exist but not really show.

Comment: @KGV Are you just copy pasting the content obtained from the output ?

Comment: To provide MWE, I gave the list. Basically, the address changes for each iteration, for which I need to get the filename after splitting it.